# How to display hardcode image on flutter which is not available in json link

Tags: json, image, flutter, dart, webapi

I am new to flutter and I'm currently developing a flutter application that fetches data from `https://private-anon-b242a842d4-carsapi1.apiary-mock.com/manufacturers`. I am displaying the image and name from the above JSON file. some of the image URL s don't have images. How can I display an image from my assets folder except for the unavailable images in the JSON file?

Home Page - where i display list of images and names

```dart
  Future<List<Car>> fetchCar() async {
    carList = [];
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://private-anon-b242a842d4-carsapi1.apiary-mock.com/manufacturers')
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> values = [];
      values = json.decode(response.body);

      if (values.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          if (values[i] != null) {
            Map<String, dynamic> map = values[i];
            carList.add(Car.fromJson(map));
          }
        }
        setState(() {
          carList;
        });
      }
      return carList;
    }else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load cars');
    }
  }

     @override
      void initState() {
        fetchCar();
        Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) => fetchCar());
        super.initState();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: carList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>DetailsPAge(
                      name: carList[index].name,
                      img_url: carList[index].img_url,
                      avg_price: carList[index].avg_price,
                      num_models:carList[index].num_models,
                      max_car_id: carList[index].max_car_id,
                      avg_horsepower: carList[index].avg_horsepower,
                )),);
              },
              child: CarCard(
                name: carList[index].name,
                img_url: carList[index].img_url
              ),
            );
          },
        ));
      }
    }
    
    class Car {
      Car({
        required this.name,
        required this.id,
        required this.img_url,
        required this.max_car_id,
        required this.num_models,
        required this.avg_price,
        required this.avg_horsepower
      });
    
      String name;
      int id;
      String img_url;
      int max_car_id;
      int num_models;
      double avg_horsepower;
      double avg_price;
    
      factory Car.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Car(
            name: json['name'],
            id: json['id'],
            img_url: json['img_url'],
            max_car_id: json['max_car_id'],
            num_models:json['num_models'],
            avg_price: json['avg_price'],
            avg_horsepower: json['avg_horsepower']
        );
      }
    }
    
    List<Car> carList = [];
```

CarCard widget - where I customize image and text

```dart
    class CarCard extends StatelessWidget {
      CarCard({
        required this.name,
        required this.img_url,
      });
    
      String name;
      String img_url;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 10, right: 10),
          child:  Container(
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey[300],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  offset: Offset(4, 4),
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  spreadRadius: 1,
                ),
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  offset: Offset(-4, -4),
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  spreadRadius: 1,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          offset: Offset(4, 4),
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          spreadRadius: 1,
                        ),
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          offset: Offset(-4, -4),
                          blurRadius: 10,
                          spreadRadius: 1,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    height: 60,
                    width: 60,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Image.network(img_url),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        FittedBox(
                          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                          child: Text(
                            name,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey[900],
                              fontSize: 25,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you try with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your question you want to display an image from your assets if there are no image in the json.
If that is what you want to do then you can use `??` operator, to check if there is an image in that json, like:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>DetailsPAge(
  name: carList[index].name,
  img_url: carList[index].img_url ?? Image.assets("<Your asset image path>"),
  avg_price: carList[index].avg_price,
  num_models:carList[index].num_models,
  max_car_id: carList[index].max_car_id,
  avg_horsepower: carList[index].avg_horsepower,
)),);
```

You can add this everywhere you want an image.

Also don't put all of your code no one is actually going to read and understand all of that; only add the code that is causing the error.

Comment: when I try to replace the above code line I got the following error...

lib/pages/homePage.dart:74:43: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null.
                  img_url: carList[index].img_url?? Image.asset('assets/images/car.png'),
                                          ^
lib/pages/homePage.dart:74:50: Error: The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
                  img_url: carList[index].img_url?? Image.asset('assets/images/car.png'),

Comment: You can also try `?` operator like `img_url: carList[index].img_url ? carList[index].img_url : Image.assets("<Your asset image path>"),`. If you want to display the image there then you have to use Image.network as mentioned in jahidul's answer

Comment: @VirajD he used Image.network, but in your code when image_url null you passed the `Image.asset`.  So you need to check in ` Image.network`

Comment: @JahidulIslam I suggested `Image.asset` because he said in his question that he wanted to display an image from his assets if there is no image in json. But if there is an image present in json then he has to use `Image.network`.

Comment: he passed url not widget in your code you passed the widget, You need to check it in carCard section, is it null then go for decision

Answer (score 0):

If the image is not in json link, then you can check it first and then show from local assets, lets try

```dart
child: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: img_url!=null && img_url.isNotEmpty
    ? Image.network(img_url)
    : Icon(Icons.add),
),
```

instead of icon you can try with

```dart
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Image.asset('images/ic_alert_triangle.png'),
),
```